# Create extension method to set all properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to create extension method

```
static IUpdatable<T> Set<T>(this IUpdatable<T> list, T item) where T : class
```

which will collapse this:

```
db.Orders
.Where(o => o.OrderId == order.OrderId)
.Where(o => o.RowVersion == order.RowVersion)
.Set(o => o.AvgDeliveryTime, order.AvgDeliveryTime)
.Set(o => o.AvgSellerTime, order.AvgSellerTime)
.Set(o => o.BuyerId, order.BuyerId)
// There are other properties
.Set(o => o.ProductName, order.ProductName)
.Set(o => o.QuantityLot, order.QuantityLot)
.Set(o => o.SellerOrderId, order.SellerOrderId)
.Update();
```

to this:

```
db.Orders
.Where(o => o.OrderId == order.OrderId)
.Where(o => o.RowVersion == order.RowVersion)
.Set(o => o, order)
.Update();
```

It should be able to add Set-method for each property.
How to implement this method?

UPD:
Something like this:

```
    public static IUpdatable<T> Set<T>(this IUpdatable<T> list, T item) where T : class 
    {
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof (T).GetProperties();

        var result = list;

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            result = result.Set(i=>prop.GetSetMethod(false), prop.GetValue(item, prop.Name) ); // This is wrong
        }

        return result;
    }
```

UPD2:
Overloads of Set-method:

```
    public static IUpdatable<T> Set<T, TV>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, Expression<Func<T, TV>> update);
    public static IUpdatable<T> Set<T, TV>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, Expression<Func<TV>> update);
    public static IUpdatable<T> Set<T, TV>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, TV value);
    public static IUpdatable<T> Set<T, TV>(this IUpdatable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, Expression<Func<T, TV>> update);
    public static IUpdatable<T> Set<T, TV>(this IUpdatable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, Expression<Func<TV>> update);
    public static IUpdatable<T> Set<T, TV>(this IUpdatable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TV>> extract, TV value);
```

Comment: Try to write that method on your own, and if you're stuck with some **specific** problem while doing so, you're welcome to update this question to include that problem. As it's currently written this question falls into the [gimme teh codez](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question) category, which isn't a good fit for any of SE sites.

Comment: @FireShock wrong. I suppose that it is EF, so you need to create `Expression` foreach `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: It is not EF - it is Linq2DB. It makes sql update-script.

Comment: Has a `Set` method some overloads? I mean this: `.Set(o => o.SellerOrderId, order.SellerOrderId)`.

Comment: Yes. I added Set-overloads to the end of my question.

Comment: It won't be easy to create such a method you want to. There is no non-generic overload for `Set`.

Comment: Yes. I want to try make overload with reflection.

Comment: What is the problem with the original method? You can see directly in the query what is happening. You can easily set only a subset of properties. Compile time errors. Can't take many seconds to type or paste each line.

Comment: The thing is that `Linq2DB` may not handle it - I think that update is done at databse side. In case of reflection, update  must have happen at server side.

Comment: @adrianm, Update method is in the database repository. We can add to the table new fields and add business logic methods. I would not want to modify the repository.

Comment: Maybe Expressions.Expression or MemberExpression can help?